# How to prevent read-write error between two events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a boolean _isTextChanged, there are two events will get access to this variable in one class. I got some read-write inconsistency which I think is caused by multi-threading issue. But not sure how to solve this problem. I tried to use Lock, but seems doesn't help. The code is like the following

```
 private void A_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    if(somecondition && !_hasTextChanged)
    {
        Dosomething();
    }
    _hasTextChanged = false;
 }


private void B_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DosomethingElse();
    _hasTextChanged = true;
}
```

The situation is that, after B_event has been called once,  A_event get called, then _hasTextChanged will be set to false, however the second time  when A_event has been called, _hasTextChanged will change to true without actually hitting the code in B_event which is the only place that set _hasTextChanged to true. I think this is a multi_threading issue. But not sure how to solve this. I tried the following code, but doesn't solve the problem

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();
private void A_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(somecondition && !_hasTextChanged)
    {
        Dosomething();
    }
    Lock(thisLock)
    {
        _hasTextChanged = false;
    }
}

private void B_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DosomethingElse();
    Lock(thisLock)
    {
        _hasTextChanged = true;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You need to hold the lock during *every* access to `_hasTextChanged`, not just some of them. Also, you probably want to set `_hasTextChanged` to false before calling `Dosomething()`, otherwise you might miss a notification.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for the lock advice, but seems didn't solve the problem. I'm wondering wht set _hasTextChanged to false before calling Dosomething() since only when _hasTextChanged  is false, can Dosomething() get executed. Thanks!

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your code at all. What purpose does `_hasTextChanged` served? Why do you want to do something if it hasn't changed? And why then do you no longer care whether it changed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My bad, I misunderstood the flow... somehow...Thank you!

Comment: How do you instantiate this class? Please use this.GetHashCode() and make sure it is the same instance id when you encounter in-consistency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking more closely at it, the first thing I noticed is you are using your shared resource -- `_hasTexstChanged` outside of a lock:

```
if(somecondition && !_hasTextChanged)
{
    Dosomething();
}
```

You need to protect *all* access -- read or write -- to resources shared across threads:

```
Lock(thisLock)
{
    if(somecondition && !_hasTextChanged)
    {
        Dosomething();
    }        
    _hasTextChanged = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but seems doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I misunderstood the workflow, problem solved, thank you!